# how to pack few .NET dll's into one dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono

I have few dll's of c# code and I want to pack it to one dll.
I am looking for something like ilmerge in linux.
Do anyone know an alternative?
Thanks,
Ohad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mkbundle:

```
$ mkbundle -o output.dll a1.dll a2.dll a3.dll
```

*output.dll* will contain a1.dll, a2.dll and a3.dll

Comment: sounds interesting - I will give it a try. is it new option?

Comment: It's no so new..see http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications for details

Answer (score 7):

[Mono.Merge](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2006/11/06/an-introduction-to-mono-merge):

```
monomerge -out output.exe input.exe input_lib.dll
```

Comment: can you give an example how to use it?

Comment: The blog post I've linked to already does provide an example.

Answer (score 5):

There is ilmerge for windows:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en